# AWS API gateway really works well but I can't run this on javascript AJAX

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I made python function using AWS lambda and connected lambda with API Gateway
After then, I tested API. It worked well.
[Testing in API Gateway was Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcaZk.jpg)

Now I tried to using this API with AJAX.
[Javascript AJAX Code was like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usCiz.jpg)

How ever result was

```
"jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 GET https://9i1jhuewmj.execute-api.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/transaction?jpgname=image.jpg net::ERR_FAILED"
```

How can  i solve this problem??

Hope for your wisdom!
Thank you

Comment: `GOOD` is not a valid json. Maybe this causes your error?

Comment: also, for future questions, please copy/paste code snippets into the question instead of posting screenshots or links to screen shots... it makes it much easier to read and easier for us to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few things.  The `content-type` header being returned is `application/json` but the response is not JSON.

But I think the main problem is that the HTTP status being returned is `301`.  This tells the browser that this resource has been moved and the browser typically expects the response to contain information on where things are moved to so it can redirect.

I suspect if you change your configuration so that a more normal response code (i.e. `200`) is returned, this will work better.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!! I have change response code to 200 and added head value        [ 'headers': {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : True
                 },] Thank you very much!!

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved the problem, glad it helped:)